# How to not show inaccessible folders when using find

Tags: unix, find, output

I'm using the find command on a Linux server. I do not have access to all directories. My command looks like this: `find . -name "filename.ending" -ls`. It finds the file I need but also lists all of the inaccessible folders - which is quite a lot. 
I could neither find an option to suppress this on the manpage nor on some other example pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
find . -iname "filename.ending" -ls 2>&1 |egrep -v "Operation not permitted|Permission denied"
find . -iname "filename.ending" -ls 2>/dev/null
```

I assume you get these two kinds of errors mostly :

- Operation not permitted
- Permission denied

If anything else is there you can add it in the `|` pipe.

**Explanation** :

`2` represents `stderr` which we are sending to stdout and using `grep` to filter out.
In second, we are dumping `2` stderr to /dev/null (it is the null device it takes any input you want and throws it away. It can be used to suppress any output)

Comment: Thanks. The first one didn't change much, I was still getting all the "Permission denied" errors. The second one worked, though. So the way I understand it is that it filters out everything that goes to stderr? Meaning I'll have to be careful with that as it would also omit an error message  I'd possibly like to see, right?

Comment: The `grep` specifically filters out just two specific error messages, and passes through the rest. The second command has exactly the problem you describe.